# SQLite sort by price doesn't work

Tags: sqlite, text, sorting, character

I have a column called price and all the values are TEXT so like this: "$26.71".
I want to sort this column in descending order but i can't because the column is not defined as INTEGER and it has a "$" character in front of all the values.
What should i do in order to make this work??
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can combine [`ltrim`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html) and [`cast`](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) to get an actual numeric from which to sort by:

```
select * from table order by cast(ltrim(price, '$') as numeric) desc
```

Note, `ltrim` also works if you have multiple currencies. Just line them all up, like `'$€'`. `ltrim` removes any and all characters from the left side until it hits a character that's not in that string.

Answer (score 2):

Mehmet, Ideally you should be storing the prices as a currency/decimal/numeric data type and appending the "$" on the UI. Eric's solution will work for your immediate problem, but as your system grows, the performance of these selects will get worse and worse.